# PHP-TO-JSON No Array [0]?

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, associative-array, zero

So, after a long three days, another issue I had is resolved, regarding php-to-json arrays. Since fixing the previous issue, have run into a another that causes a break in the output using foreach.

Looking at the var_dump, there seems to be an issue:

1. The first array has no 0 yet contains all the named keys.
2. Thereafter the arrays are numbered: 0, 1, etc, but no named keys.
3. The first repeats at the end of the output with a consecutive integer "1".

Using [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) tested and it returned valid.
Here is the [output link](http://api.mutrs.me/artists/).

PS: Ignore the json_pretty_print. I did it just to see the structure more clearly.

```
[
{
    "muid": "IMDBTFKG3MJOZPE0AAVA",
    "bandname": "In Hoodies",
    "core": {
        "joined": "Wed 26 August 2015",
        "bandbio": "Broken Tambourine Music",
        "genre": "Popular",
        "subgenre": "Brit"
    },

 "0": [
        "IM5LGM02MFS8RJLKGY9W",
        "Marbles For Zen",
        {
            "joined": "Sun 01 March 2015",
            "bandbio": "Zen And Marbles",
            "genre": "Rhythm Blues",
            "subgenre": "Dixie Rhythm"
        },

...

"1": [
    "IMA3YNBKZQDNR9RBCSRI",
    "Frankie Storm",
    {
        "joined": "Sat 21 February 2015",
        "bandbio": "Just registered. Bio coming soon.",
        "genre": "Popular",
        "subgenre": ""
    },
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think you forgot to ask.

Comment: Apologies. The numbered items where intended to be questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a little confused on the structure here:

It appears you have an array that only has one element, that element being one giant object.

Inside of that object are properties, the first three properties being `muid`, `bandname` and `core`. Each property after that being numerated starting at 0, this is probably the stem of your confusion. The `0`, `1`...are not indexes, they are actually properties of the original object you can tell this because they are wrapped in double-quotes....

Comment: A.O., any reason why they are appearing as properties of the array. Yes, am a little confused on the structuring. The goal is to iterate each mysqi result as an array.

Comment: *properties of the *object*....And you'll have to ask `mutrs.me` why they chose that structure, either way it should be easy to iterate over these properties, there's plenty of info on here how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

Huge thanks to [A.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2276042/a-o) for bringing the *properties of the object* to my attention. It appears the conflict was quite simple:

Original:

```
$meso[]=array();
```

Correct:

```
$meso=[];
```

So simple, yes? It pays to pay attention.
Following the correct entrance to the array, using

```
array_push($meso, [( <--- objects here ---> )]);
```

Produces the perfect result.
Complete the function with **json_encode** and *voilà* a beautiful output.

Cheers and Happy Hacking!

Comment: glad you got it figured out! :)